# Merge Select Statements in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 Select Statements, but I need to merge both results, and show `PRIMARY_MATERIAL` beside the `SECONDARY_MATERIAL` column. I am currently using UNION which displays everything in rows (about 300 rows), but I really only need 150 Rows, and want it displayed in extra columns instead.

```
SELECT RM_Materials.MaterialCode MatCode,
       RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions.ShortDescription ProcessArea,
       RM_MRPAttributes.AttributeValue AttValue
FROM   DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions
       INNER JOIN (DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_Materials
                   INNER JOIN DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_MRPAttributes
                           ON (RM_Materials.MaterialUID = RM_MRPAttributes.MaterialUID)
                              AND (RM_Materials.InternalVersionNo = RM_MRPAttributes.MaterialVersionNo))
               ON RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions.MRPAttributeDefinitionsUID = RM_MRPAttributes.MRPAttributeDefinitionsUID
WHERE  RM_Materials.ActiveTF = 1
       AND RM_MRPAttributes.ActiveTF = 1
       AND "RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions"."ActiveTF" = 1
       AND "RM_Materials"."DeletedTF" = 0
       AND "RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions"."ShortDescription" = N'PRIMARY_MATERIAL'
       AND "RM_Materials".ActiveTF = 1
UNION
SELECT RM_Materials.MaterialCode MatCode,
       RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions.ShortDescription ProcessArea,
       RM_MRPAttributes.AttributeValue AttValue
FROM   DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions
       INNER JOIN (DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_Materials
                   INNER JOIN DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_MRPAttributes
                           ON (RM_Materials.MaterialUID = RM_MRPAttributes.MaterialUID)
                              AND (RM_Materials.InternalVersionNo = RM_MRPAttributes.MaterialVersionNo))
               ON RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions.MRPAttributeDefinitionsUID = RM_MRPAttributes.MRPAttributeDefinitionsUID
WHERE  RM_Materials.ActiveTF = 1
       AND RM_MRPAttributes.ActiveTF = 1
       AND "RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions"."ActiveTF" = 1
       AND "RM_Materials"."DeletedTF" = 0
       AND "RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions"."ShortDescription" = N'SECONDARY_MATERIAL'
       AND "RM_Materials".ActiveTF = 1
```

Comment: Do you have any duplicates to remove? Otherwise, do `UNION ALL` to get all rows, faster.

Comment: I have no duplicates to remove. Unfortunately, using UNION or UNION ALL returns everything in Rows. I need a Column displaying the AttValue for PRIMARY_MATERIAL, and another column beside it displaying the AttValue for SECONDARY_MATERIAL, for each MatCode.

Answer (score 0):

I think conditional aggregation will do what you want.  However, your query is rather hard to follow.  I think this is the solution:

```
SELECT m.MaterialCode as MatCode,
       d.ShortDescription as ProcessArea, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ShortDescription = N'PRIMARY_MATERIAL' THEN a.AttributeValue 
           END) as PrimaryMaterial_AttValue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ShortDescription = N'SECONDARY_MATERIAL' THEN a.AttributeValue 
           END) as SecondaryMaterial_AttValue 
FROM DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_Materials m INNER JOIN
     DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_MRPAttributes a
     ON m.MaterialUID = a.MaterialUID AND m.InternalVersionNo = a.MaterialVersionNo INNER JOIN
     DMI_Manu32.dbo.RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions d
     ON d.MRPAttributeDefinitionsUID = a.MRPAttributeDefinitionsUID
WHERE m.ActiveTF = 1 AND a.ActiveTF = 1 AND
      d.ActiveTF = 1 AND
      m.DeletedTF = 0
GROUP BY m.MaterialCode, d.ShortDescription;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to read and to write.
- Parentheses in the `FROM` clause are not needed, in general.  And, with `INNER JOIN`, they are never needed.  Parentheses usually cause confusion.
- There is no need to repeat conditions in the `WHERE` clause (such as `"RM_Materials".ActiveTF=1`).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I agree with Aliases. I am getting an error, Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near 'MAX'. I tried a few changes and they didn't work. Any ideas to get around this error? Thanks a mill.

Comment: It should be a comma at the end of the previous row. (I'll edit.)

Comment: Missing table in last INNER JOIN... No, wait, simply remove that `INNER JOIN` directly following `ON`?

Answer (score 0):

Just a single query with:

```
AND "RM_MRPAttributeDefinitions"."ShortDescription" IN (N'PRIMARY_MATERIAL',N'SECONDARY_MATERIAL' )
```

Think that may give you what you are looking for

Comment: I want to stay away from Union as Union displays everything in 3 Columns. Where as I want to display the results in 5 or 6 Columns, side by side. Any other suggestions?